# Blazor Server application is slow when there is no internet available

Tags: c#, iis, networking, blazor-server-side

In the domain we have two types of networks. One type is allowed to connect to the internet and the other does not allow connections to the internet. The internal network is available to both.
We have a webserver in the network that hosts a Blazor Server application (using iis). The server is in the network that can use the internet. Now when i use my laptop that is also in the network that can connect to the internet, the website on the server is fast and gives me a snappy response. When i open the same site on a computer that is in the network that is not allowed to connect to the internet, the loading speeds are dramatically decreased. We see a slight increase when we set the protocol to http instead of https, but it is not a game changer.
We see that the data is loaded realy fast but the network request takes up to 6.5 seconds and the loading of data 29 miliseconds.

Anyone have any ideas?

- We switched the application from https to http. This was a slight increase.
- We used wireshark to check the networktraffic but we see the delays in there as well. The connection itself is good not red flags.
- We changed the underlying platform of the application from .net 6 to .net 7. This did not make any difference.
- We changed the deployment mode from framework-dependend to self-contained. Still no difference.
- As soon as we enable the internet for the network, the site is fast again.

**UPDATE 26-01-2023**

After some more research we figured out that there are two ip addresses that need to be let through to make it fast again. The IP's are 142.250.179.131 and 23.2.226.23. The first IP is an IP owned by Google and has something to do with gstatic, and the second is from a company named Akamai Technologies.

None of the nuget packages or references in the application code reference any of the packages created by Akamai Technologies or Google. Or is there something else i am missing?

Comment: Based on your description, I would like to know if there are some special namespaces and related codes included in your program. Just like `System.net.dns.gethostentry` or something else.

Comment: Below are some namespaces: -System.Net -Microsoft.AspNetCore -Microsoft.JSInterop -Majorsoft.Blazor -TableDependency.SqlClient -Microsoft.Extensions -System.Threading -Migradoc -System.IO -System.Diagnostics -System.Text -Newtonsoft.Json -Syncfusion.Blazor

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this is the case. I think this also needs to narrow down the scope of this issue. Have you tried to access the site directly using the domain name and port? For this result, you may need to take different actions:

1. Issue still occurs. Then this problem may be related to the application code development, you need to review the code and troubleshoot.
2. Issue resolved. Then you may need to check the performance of IIS server. Try to use the `Debug Diagnostic Tool` and check its performance. Something like this: [image]